# How to get the Manage metadata service name using the Metadata field name?

Tags: sharepoint-server, development, taxonomyfieldvalue

In my SharePoint list I have two metadata fields. Both are different metadata services. Using spfield I will get the all taxonomy fields from the list. In this scenario I know the field name but I don't know the Metadata service name and Term names.

Using the taxonomy field name how can I get the Metadata service name and related all terms from the Metadata service using C#?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have the correct permissions (are you SP Admin? though perhaps 'edit' permissions might be sufficient(?)) you can check this in the Site Settings menu > Term Store Management Tool.

From there you can see an overview of all the term store tags/fields.

Comment: i want to retrieve and store this terms in Datatable using c#

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned you don't know the term names, I assumed you are not term store admin. You can use REST Service to retrieve the term names (or using the [search query tool](https://sp2013searchtool.codeplex.com/) is more intuitive.) From there, you will be able to retrieve the metadata value via REST API.

Answer (score 0):

We cannot get the managed metadata service name using the metadata field name.

You could go to central administration->manage service applications->get the managed metadata service name.

More references:

Foreach Managed Metadata Term.

https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/office/Foreach-Managed-Metadata-54f7a5e5

SP 2010: Introduction to programmatically working with Taxonomies in SharePoint Server 2010.

https://zimmergren.net/sp-2010-introduction-to-programmatically-working-with-taxonomies-in-sharepoint-server-2010/